# Setting new value for key/setting if it exists in sbt build?

Tags: sbt, sbteclipse

Is it possible to check whether a key exists, and only define a new value for that key if it exists in the build?

The use case is that eclipse users on our team use [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) (installed as a local plugin), and non-eclipse users do not install the plugin.  As soon as I define sbteclipse-specific keys in the build script, it breaks for the non-eclipse users.

The needed definition is:

```
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.Resource
```

This definition belongs to the build script (as opposed to being defined by individual users) because the build classpath is a property of the build/project.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `?` to see if there was a previous value of a setting when defining that setting.

The real issue here is that you need the *types* from the Eclipse plugin, which means that if it's not on the classpath, you can't reference the `.createSrc` key at all, because Scala will choke on any import of the plugin.

You have two options currently:

1. Install the sbteclipse plugin on the project itself.  Only Eclipse users will call the tasks.
2. Use reflection to grab the sbteclipse key off the classpath and do some dirty magic.

The sbt team is working on/proposing two solutions to fix this:

1. AutoPlugins -  Releasing with sbt 0.13.5

   With AutoPlugins you can specify a bunch of settings and dependencies on other plugins that get automatically included. Once the sbteclipse plugin is updated for AutoPlugins, you'll be able to do the following:

   ```
   object MyCompanyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
     override def requires: Plugins = EclipsePlugin
     override def trigger = allRequirements
     override def projectSettings = Seq(
       EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.Resource
     )
   }
   ```

   Then, have your Eclipse users depend on this "company" plugin which will automatically "enhance" the existing sbteclipse plugin with your desired settings.
2. There's a proposal for a notion of "build level" where you can optionally enable/disable .sbt files from being compiled/loaded such that you could, e.g., drop the sbteclipse plugin and have it only enabled for users who want it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'll probably just add sbteclipse to the project itself.  It really would be nice for sbt to have a bit more flexibility in this regard, but I understand that an sbt script is more or less a Scala program which must be typesafe to compile.  Lacking a better answer, I'll award the bounty to you.